# What is the purpose of virtual in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-relationship

I am a beginner to Entity Framework. I have got some terms which are creating problems. I am considering code-first schema

1. **1-to-1** is resolved by by making a property of the child class in parent class and in child class we marks the id of parent class as foreign key.

   Like

   ```
   public class Parent{
      //code 
      public Child Child{get; set;}
   }

   public class Child{
      [ForeignKey("Parent")]
      public int ParentId{get; set;}
   }
   ```
2. A **1-to-many** relation we use

   ```
   public class Parent {
      //code 
      public IList<Child> Child { get; set; }
   }

   public class Child {
      [ForeignKey("Parent")]
      public int ParentId{get; set;}
   }
   ```

   Is this the correct approach?
3. `\*-\*` is resolved by adding `IList<class>` in both classes.

But I was solving a problem where I have 2 classes `Categories` and `Products`.

In `Product` class a property is defined as

```
public class Products {
   public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

And in the `Category` class, products are called in this way

```
public class Categories {
   public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

I am confused what is the purpose of `virtual Category` in product?

Anyone answer please to resolve my confusion

Comment: It's explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: The `virtual` is a C# keyword to indicate that child classes can override the method or property.

Comment: @Bun - With EF, it specifies that related child entities should be loaded when the parent is.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil the link you posted says that virtual is used for lazy-binding and bun is saying its c# keyword and has no relation which entity?

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil is right - the `virtual` keyword in an EF entity specifies that the related objects (here: the categories of the product) will be **lazy loaded** - only when you need them, not when you retrieve the `Product`

Comment: @HassaanKhan I was not aware that virtual had a different meaning when used with Entity, so listen to the other guys, they look like they know what they are talking about ;)

Comment: @Bun that virtual was really an headache for me. Hopefully understood

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, EF uses the `virtual` keyword to enable lazy loading. The way it does this is by using what is known as a [dynamic proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx).

If you are debugging you might notice that the type of your entity is not what you think it is:

> Proxy types have names that look something like this:
>   System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies
>   .Blog_5E43C6C196972BF0754973E48C9C941092D86818CD94005E9A759B70BF6E48E6

Entity Framework sees your Entity has the virtual keyword, and will create a dynamic proxy by inheriting from your class and overriding the properties that are marked virtual to enable lazy-loading for those properties.

As mentioned in the msdn I linked to, you will not get a dynamic proxy when you create an instance of your entity using the new keyword (and therefore will not get lazy loading):

```
var blog1 = new Blog(); // not a dynamic proxy
var blog2 = db.Blogs.Create(); // this is a dynamic proxy
var blog3 = db.Blogs.Find(1); // this is a dynamic proxy
```